# Editing Exif Data using filename pictures

Tags: image, jpeg, exif

I own more or less one thousand of pictures which don't contain the Exif Data. Because of I would restore at least the taken date using the filename, is there a way to edit those fields programmatically?

The filename is something like this: IMG_20130326_232320.jpg

Thank you for the attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do it quite easily with the [exiv2](http://exiv2.org/) utility and some shell scripting on a *nix system.

Supposing you are in the directory containing the file you can do something like this:

```
for pic in *.jpg ; do
  date = $( echo $pic | cut -d. -f1 | cut -d_ -f2-3 )
  exiv2 -M"set Exif.Image.DateTime Ascii $date" $pic
done
```

This will store a "date_time" string in the `DateTime` field of the image. As you can see, the `Exif.Image.DateTime` field accepts an ASCII string, so you can do whatever processing you want to get a better looking date. In your example, the field would then contain the string `20130326_232320`, but you can do pretty much whatever you want with a bit of parsing.

A (maybe better, depending on your needs) alternative to EXIF is using the IPTC format and the corresponding `IPTC.Date` and `IPTC.Time` fields, which requires a specific data format but are easier to understand by photo management programs.

The `exiv2` man page specifies that the `IPTC.Date` format is `YYYY-MM-DD`, while the `IPTC.Time` format is `HH:MM:SS+|-HH:MM` (local hour plus local offset from UTC). You can set them in the same way, but it will require a bit more filename parsing, of course.

The `exiv2` tool is also available for Windows, so if you know a bit of batch scripting it shouldn't be too hard to implement it there.

Comment: Great, thank you! Do you know if exiv2 can modify the mp4 video too?

Comment: As far as I know, no. There was [a ticket](http://dev.exiv2.org/issues/813) about video metadata, but I can't understand what exactly happened to it.

You can try [ExifTool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExifTool) for that, it can't add new metadata but it can edit the existing ones.